# Make element in shadow dom 100% of custom element height with min-height and border while also scaling parent if overflowing

Tags: css, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am making a custom element that functions as a textarea with syntax highlighting and some other features. I've simplified it to a custom element with a div inside that gains height when clicking the page.

To make the custom element have a default height and be able to increase in height due to more content, I used `min-height: 40vh`. The problem is that `height: 100%` in the div inside the shadow dom doesn't work. It doesn't expand to 100% of the height of the shadow dom / the custom element's inner height. However, the custom element does still grow to fit the div when needed.

Note that the custom element uses `box-sizing: border-box` and also has a border.

### What I have tried:

I have tried all these on both Chrome and Firefox and none of them work **as desired** on either browser.

#### `height: anything between 0 and 40vh` on custom element

This works except the custom element doesn't grow to fit the div when the div grows bigger than the custom element.

#### `min-height: inherit` on div

This works except it includes the border of the custom element parent, which makes the parent grow bigger than 40vh by default using `box-sizing: border-box`. I want the custom element to have `min-height: 40vh` with `box-sizing: border-box`.

#### Flexbox

Flexbox on the custom element doesn't affect elements in the shadow root.

### The code with the problem

Note that **StackOverflow doesn't give the snippet enough screen height to show the problem**, and clicking "Expand snippet" and then running it has the same problem, **so make sure to first start it and then click "Full page"**, and then clicking the page will make the div grow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            my-element {
                border: 40px solid gray;
                min-height: 40vh;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-element></my-element>

        <script>
            class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
        
                    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
                    const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
                    stylesheet.replaceSync(`
                        * {
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                        }
                        :host {
                            display: block;
                        }
                        div {
                            background: green;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%; /* not working */
                        }
                    `);
                    shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet];

                    const div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerText = "Hello";
                    shadow.appendChild(div);
                    document.body.onclick = () => {
                        div.innerText += "\nHi";
                    };
                }
            }
            customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I could make a hacky solution using JS but I want to see if there is a way to do this using just CSS.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I tend to use `grid` with a single row and column to adjust sizing of multiple elements to the largest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @LajosArpad With `height: 100%`, the div doesn't take up 100% of the height of the shadow dom of the parent (custom element). It does however make the parent grow when it grows larger than the parent's content box.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you, I have made the code into a runnable snippet, but StackOverflow doesn't give it a height, which is needed to show the problem. At the moment you have to first start it and then click "Full page"

Comment: Is my interpretation correct?? You want TWO behaviors for ONE ``DIV``? (1) Size ``DIV`` to component height when content is **less than** component height; (2) increase size when ``DIV`` content **overflows** component height. It wouldn't be a hacky JS solution, check height for every added line, and toggle a ``style``: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/w704hdvu/

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes, that interpretation is correct, and it is possible except for here where there is a shadow dom separating the parent and the div, and a parent border, and box-sizing:border-box all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

I ended up just adding the elements as direct children of the custom element, and abandoning the shadow dom. This comes with the drawback that global css will affect it but it's worth it in my opinion.

Btw, I had to move the code to `connectedCallback` in the custom element class because you can't append children to the custom element from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` is occupying 100% of the height of its parent element, which is `my-element`. If you want it to occupy the entirety of the screen, then you will need to set its parent to have 100% height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
            }
            my-element {
                border: 40px solid gray;
                min-height: 40vh;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-element></my-element>

        <script>
            class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
                constructor() {
                    super();
        
                    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
                    const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet();
                    stylesheet.replaceSync(`
                        * {
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                        }
                        :host {
                            display: block;
                        }
                        div {
                            background: green;
                            width: 100%;
                            height: 100%; /* not working */
                        }
                    `);
                    shadow.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet];

                    const div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerText = "Hello";
                    shadow.appendChild(div);
                    document.body.onclick = () => {
                        div.innerText += "\nHi";
                    };
                }
            }
            customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My div is not occupying 100% of the height of `my-element` if you run the code in true fullscreen. That is the whole problem. I noted in the question that the snippet only shows the problem if you first run it and then click "Full page" (in StackOverflow.com). It also shows the problem properly if you make a html file and open that in your browser separately.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't be done with pure CSS, and you do need JavaScript,
then I would **toggle** a `<STYLE>` inside shadowDOM

- If the content is less than the Component `clientHeight` ***enable*** that `<STYLE>`
- When the content *overflows* the Web Component, ***disable*** the `<STYLE>`

This way you can add more styling (`border-color:blue` in below example)
And you are not sticking *inline* styles on an element.

https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/w704hdvu/

I refactored your code so it can run as inline SO snippet

Initial state of the `<STYLE>` is disabled to show the RED background.
After first click it shows correct state.

```html
<style>
  my-element {
    box-sizing: border-box; border: 10px solid gray;
    min-height: 120px; display: block;
  }
</style>
<my-element></my-element>
<script>
  const element = (t,p={}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(t), p);
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
        .append( 
          element("STYLE", { innerHTML: `:host { background:red } #container { background:green }` }),
          this.heightStyle = element("STYLE",{
            initialHeight : this.clientHeight, // might as well store it here
            innerHTML : `:host { border-color:blue!important} 
                         #container{ height:${this.clientHeight}px }`,
            onload : () => this.heightStyle.disabled = true,// demo only, show red
          }),
          this.container = element("DIV", { id : "container", 
                                            onclick : () => this.addLine(),
                                            innerHTML: "Hello Web Component (click me)" }) );
      this.addLine();
    }
    addLine( newdiv = element("DIV",{ innerText:"FORCE LINE HEIGHT" }) , 
             container=this.container, style=this.heightStyle ){
      style.disabled = true; // get correct #container height
      container.append( newdiv );
      newdiv.innerText = "clientHeight:" + this.clientHeight + "px";    
      style.disabled = container.clientHeight > style.initialHeight;
    }
  });
</script>
Click GREEN 
Green DIV should "cover" the red background, but also overflow
```

Comment: This might have worked but I think there would be special cases to handle so I ended up abandoning the shadow dom and appending the children as children to the custom element directly. This allows flexbox to solve the issue.

Comment: That is rule #1 for Web Component development: _**Do I really need shadowDOM? _it is_ optional!**_